# What is the difference between "user" and "account" in FileZilla site manager?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

In FileZilla, there are "user" and "account" in the site manager as the logon type is account. What is the difference between "user" and "account"?

---

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

There is this question on Stack Overflow: [What is FTP ACCT command for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24974062) The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978840) is:

> USER specifies the user used for authorization. Once authorized the user might need to select between various accounts it has. While this might not be a common use case with most servers, remember that ftp is not only usable for systems where each user has only a single account, but that its a really old protocol and was developed in mind with mainframes, VMS and others which might be different or more flexible when separating authorization and account.

<sub>Note: if you find this useful then consider upvoting the original answer on SO.</sub>